# Should the cursor be changed before or after the "try", and why?

Tags: c#, winforms

Like this:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
try {
  . . .
} finally {
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

or this:

```
try {
  Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
  . . .
} finally {
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

?

Comment: why would you put it inside the try, it doesnt throw an exception does it?

Comment: It is recommended (Self paced kit book for Microsoft certification exam 70-536) that all code except for simple harmless things such as declarations is put inside try-catch block and determining what could be harmless or not carries a risk of wrong decision, to be on the safe side you can put it inside try-catch block if you're not sure whether it can throw an exception.

Comment: nop. no exceptions. < http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no harm in putting the first cursor assignment inside the try block. As others have noted, if you know for sure that the assignment can never throw an exception, it doesn't strictly need to be inside the try block. If you're not sure, it's better to put it inside the try block.

As a general coding pattern, if you're unsure whether a statement could throw an exception, put it inside the try block.  It's better to put it inside the try block and not need it than to assume/guess wrong and put it outside the try block when you really do need it inside.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the two approaches, since assigning a pre-defined cursor to `Cursor.Current` will not throw an Exception.  If you were loading the cursor from a resource file, that act could in fact throw an Exception (e.g. if the specified resource is not found).

Important is to set the cursor to the desired state in the `finally` block, which you do in both examples.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself, will the result of that line throw an exception?  In this simple case it doesn't  matter as long as if and only if any exceptions are thrown you return to a normal state in your finally clause.  Personally, I would not throw that line `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor` as that will not throw an exception (you are simply making an assignment).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you put it inside, *unless it will be throwing an Exception*.

If it does throw an exception, then you should just handle the specific type of exception that it throws in the `catch` block, or handle final arrangements and deallocate resources before the program exits using the `finally` block.

Here's some good info for you to read up on:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Comment: You don't handle specific exceptions in a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the Cursor setter before the try. The reason is that your try/finally approach is ensuring that the code within the try-block doesn't affect Cursor if it throws an exception. However, you're not trying to guard against an error from the Cursor property itself. If there's an error there, then you will want to either deal with it separately, or let it result in an unhandled exception which will tear down the app. The last thing you want is for setting Cursor to throw an exception, only to get another exception while trying to set it again in your finally block: you will only see the second exception in your crash report and it will probably send you down the wrong path when you go to debug it, and waste a lot of your time.